# Least Questions to study?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Let's say I have a question bank of 10 questions.
The format for my exam is as such 
1.) There are 4 Sections 
2.)Each section has 2 questions out of which any 1 is to be attempted

So my question is, what is the least amount of questions I must study but still be able to meet the requirement and answer each section.

Thanks

Comment: So your worst nightmare is that you study $n$ problems and you get a maximum of $3$ categories. How big is $n$ that the worst possible is $3$ categories? Add 1 after you find that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to study nine questions. If you only studied eight, it would be possible the two questions you did not study were both in the same section. With nine, it is impossible to be unprepared for a section, since that would require having two questions you did not study.